# Does Leafletjs Map works on china?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Google Maps are blocked in china. So, we are looking for alternate solutions that have similar features like Google map.
I found leafletjs for Map. but want to make sure that it works in china.

Answer (score 4):

It should work. Leaflet as library should work without any restrictions I believe that tile maps should be the problem.  Lucky, you have an extension to Leaflet that contains configurations for various Chinese tile providers.

But more about that on this [site](https://github.com/htoooth/Leaflet.ChineseTmsProviders).

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use many different maps with Leafletjs. I use Open Street maps in my app.

https://www.openstreetmap.org

You can specify open street as your base map:

```
var openStreet = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
    {
        maxZoom: 18,
        subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
    });
```

You can add to leaflet with:

```
openStreet.addTo(map);
```