# Is leaflet with OSM accessible in China?

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap, accessible

Good day!

I just want to know whether leaflet is usable in China continent.

My service uses googleMap API but google map is not working in China.

So If leaflet with OSM is accessible in China, I want to take it for next project.

Is leaflet with OSM able to use in China?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Leafletjs Map works on china?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42944212/does-leafletjs-map-works-on-china)

Answer (score 1):

It had been working but at some point recently it became blocked. Pulling from a.tile.openstreetmap.org is coming up blank for our China office and shows up as blocked on the firewall test sites.